# How can we get the sum of different columns in datagridview?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am trying to add the sum of different columns from data grid view and in data grid view there are several rows. If there are 10 rows in data grid view than there should an option that will calculate the sum of several columns and then it assign the value to a variable after that next row will calculated.

Any Ideas???????
[image]

Comment: If you are summing all columns then that could simply be another property on your data objects bound to the grid.

Comment: If you anly need a sum of all cells, maybe you should just iterate through all columns (for (int i = 0; i <datagridview.Columns.Count; i++) and add value from cell to some variable like dSum = dSum + datagridView.Rows[yourrownumberhere].Cells[i].Value()

Comment: @ŁukaszMotyczka your code is great for once. I have some different situation. I have to calculate the sum of these fee's to print thousand different vouchers.

Comment: I am not sure if I'm following you. Can you post some example?